# Width of text box jQuery mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have label and text box in jQuery mobile and i am trying to change the width of the text box.

For some reason after i am changing the width, lets say for 60% i am still seeing the rest of the 40% almost transparent.

I am adding also a photo of it in order to be more clear.

This is the code:

Html:

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <form>
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                 <label for="sales1">Sales:</label>
                 <input type="text" id="sales" value="">
            </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#sales {    
    width: 60%;   
}
```

[image: This is what i am getting.]

How do i change the width without seeing the extra 40% of the text box?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: actually it is for mobile phones but i am using chrome, firefox and safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using jQuery mobile forms, the inputs are enclosed onto a div which holds the width as 100%. To change the width of your text field, you rather need to change its value of the parent, not from the input itself.
You can achieve this with jQuery:

```
$('#sales').parent().width($('#sales').parent().width() * .4);
```

The above code is setting the width of the parent div to 40% of its actual value. Here is an example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qctddeza/

[.width() function reference](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

[.parent() function reference](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Edit:

You would be able to do it with CSS only, but not selecting with an id, as you cannot get the parent of the input element. A general styling can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/01qjw7ev/4/).

*Code taken from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_forms_inputs).*

Comment: the javascript option did not work for me but the css one worked perfectly!

Comment: This might happen because of an _!important_ mention in the styling of the parent div. Glad to hear the CSS option helped you though.